# Initialize a Python Constant Using a Function Declared After It

Tags: python

I'm used to writing the following piece of code in Java or C# without errors. It allows me to centralize the conversion of string to a floating point representation. Unlike the simple implementation below, I have a lot more going on in there to handle commas or brackets for negative numbers in Excel.

I can understand why Python gives an error. Python code is not compiled but interpreted in sequence and `toFloat` does not exist for Python while its processing the declaration of `ZERO` .

I was wondering if there is a pythonic way of doing this without having to pull the `toFloat` function to another module OR without having to not declare `ZERO` at the very top?

```
ZERO = toFloat('0.0')    # <-- ERROR on this line "Undefined variable: toFloat"

def toFloat(val):
    """Function to convert a string to a float"""
    return Decimal(val)
```

Comment: Why aren't you declaring the function before calling it?!

Comment: @sweeneyrod I prefer to keep the constants at the top of the module.

Comment: The issue is the number of passes performed when compiling, not that "Python code is not compiled".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I didn't know that, thanks! So the Java or .Net compilers actually do more than 1 pass?

Comment: Java and C#, yes. They build a symbol table during the first pass, and resolve unknown symbols during the second.

Comment: @Danish But this won't ever happen in python, as you can redefine your symbols as many times you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following piece of code, which I think is clean and keeps the declarations at the top while allowing me to keep the code below but still use it to initialize my variables.

```
class Tools(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ZERO = self.toFloat('0.0')

    def toFloat(self, val):
        return float(val)

tools=Tools()
print tools.ZERO
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an undefined symbol, which is a bad idea in many languages.
Python has no idea, what the symbol `toFloat` might refer to.

For illustration, what would you expect this code to do? Should `ZERO` be zero or one?

```
ZERO = toFloat('0.0')

def toFloat(val): return Decimal(val)
def toFloat(val): return 1
```

Or in this case:

```
ZERO = toFloat('0.0')

if ZERO: from libone import toFloat #where toFloat returns 0
else: from libtwo import toFloat #where toFloat returns 1
```

The thing is you can redefine your symbols as many times you want. E.g. this is legit code:

```
def f(): return 0
print(f())
def f(): return 1
print(f())
```

---

If it is of vital importance that `ZERO` be declared at the top of your code, maybe you can use this ugly hack for your constants:

Put this in another file, let's say const.py:

```
class Constant:
    def __init__(self, cf):
        self.cf = cf

    @property
    def c(self):
        try: return self.__c
        except: self.__c = self.cf()
        return self.__c
```

And then in your file, you can use:

```
from const import Constant

ZERO = Constant(lambda: toFloat('0.0'))
def toFloat(x): return 42
print(ZERO.c)
```

Comment: I would expect the same error. I get why it doesn't work in Python. I was wondering if there was a language feature that I didn't know of. For Example, something like this was done in C++ using prototypes and this simply works in languages like Java & C#

Comment: Can you redefine functions in Java?

Comment: So how would you fix my code? Maybe you can add a separate answer with the solution to this question using redefinition.

Comment: @Danish There is no fix. You cannot access undefined symbols.

Comment: @Danish I couldn't add a "fix", but maybe a hack that suits you.

Comment: Thanks for that hack. What do you think of my answer below?

Comment: @Danish I can't see how it relates to your question.

Comment: The constant `ZERO` is initialized before the the `toFloat` function is declared in code. Title of my question - "Initialize a Python Constant Using a Function Declared After It"

Comment: @Danish No, it is not. First `toFloat` is declared before `init` is called and inside it `toFloat` is accessed.

Comment: I meant to use the word "Declare" to strictly mean the sequence in which I announce my code to Python. Hence, in my mind, I've "declared" `ZERO` before `toFloat` *But* Python "Initialized" `toFloat` before `ZERO`. Maybe I used the wrong word, but my intention is to keep the code implementing `toFloat` after initialization of `ZERO`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Pythonic way of doing this:

```
def toFloat(val):
    """Function to convert a string to a float"""
    return Decimal(val)

ZERO = toFloat('0.0')
```

Preferring to define your constants before things they use just isn't how things work in Python. The best thing to do IMHO would be learning to like this way of doing things, rather than relying on clumsy workarounds. Python isn't like Java, not everything has to be wrapped in a load of classes. This often simplifies code a lot. As a general rule of thumb, if you make a class in Python, such as `Tools` in your example, that doesn't have a clear concrete purpose, you should probably take it out of the program.

Comment: I can totally appreciate how this is more Pythonic. However, for practical reason, I wanted the constants and configs on the top so that my co-workers don't have trouble supporting code that I wrote while I disappear on vacation. It feels like the best things to do would be to create separation using multiple modules